# How to add local package to Xcode Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I want to add SwiftyDropbox package locally to my Xcode Swift project so it builds fastest.

I added dependency to SwiftyDropbox github URL and it runs ok, but takes over a minute to build after Xcode clean (ie. realclean).

I'm following Apple's article "Editing a Package Dependency as a Local Package" but step 3. doesn't work: "Select the Swift package’s folder in Finder and drag it into the Project navigator".

[image]

Comment: Are you dragging the folder into the project or the `KP_to_iOS_5.xcodeproj` file? Apple's tutorial says: "Select the Swift package’s **folder** in Finder and drag it into the Project navigator."

Comment: I'm dragging folder SwiftyDropbox-master, which I cloned from github and it doesn't have .xcodeproj file.

Comment: Sorry - I thought your picture showed you dragging a `.xcodeproj` file to Xcode.

Comment: Same problem here. Following Apple description and stuck at step 3. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've added it to the local repo and then added the local path to the folder of that repo.

`file:///absolute_path`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Add Local...** button
[image: use "Add Local..." button]